# Splitting an array of letters and numbers into two separate arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, numbers

I received some answers for this question yesterday, but this code doesn't work exactly the way I need it to, and I can't reply to anybody on my original thread with as few words as required.

I'm trying to take inputs from an input box, split them, and then sort them into two arrays: one for numbers, the other for non-numbers.

Here's my code:

```
var splitResult = listResult.split(separator);
    var L = 0;
    letterArray = [];
    numberArray = [];
   for (; L < splitResult.length; L++) {
   if(isNaN(splitResult[L]) && typeof splitResult[L] === 'string') {
    letterArray.push(splitResult[L]);
    L = L + 1
  } else if (Number(splitResult[L])) {
    numberArray.push(splitResult[L]);
    L = L + 1;
```

My problems arise when I check my arrays. When the input is mixed, I get my numberArray looking perfect, but there is absolutely no output to letterArray, not even undefined or NaN or 0. Also, when the input is numbers only, so for instance: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
numberArray shows up as 1,3,5,7,

Please tell me what's going wrong if you can.

Comment: can you post the alphanumeric input and the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The increment `L = L + 1;` is not required.

Since in the `for` loop, you are incrementing the value of L as L++, so another increment for L is not required.

```
var splitResult = listResult.split(separator);

        var L = 0;
        letterArray = [];
        numberArray = [];
       for (; L < splitResult.length; L++) {
       if(isNaN(splitResult[L]) && typeof splitResult[L] === 'string') {
        letterArray.push(splitResult[L]);

      } else if (Number(splitResult[L])) {
        numberArray.push(splitResult[L]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're adding L + 1 twice in the loop, skipping some characters.

remove

```
    L = L + 1;
```

from each if statement